# Bounding box for handwritten text

Tags: python, image-processing, text-recognition

I have a completed handwritten form (form is printed however, it is completed with handwritten information) and I wanted to extract only the handwritten text from the form....

Currently, I have hard-coded the bounding box with openCV and used CNN model to extract the handwritten text. The form is in various template and everytime I will not be able to use the hard-coded bounding box. Is there a way where the bounding box is created automatically based on the handwritten text? Please suggest your options.

Comment: Could you add your input image?

Comment: The link below is an example of an image that I have... I would basically like to extract the handwritten text from this form.

http://doa.alaska.gov/dgs/property/manual/02-622.GIF

Comment: Kathiravan Saimoorthy did you get the idea about how to do it or did you implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a paper on [text detection using a CNN](https://aaai.org/ocs/index.php/AAAI/AAAI17/paper/download/14202/14295).  Also here's a [whole repo. on papers in OCR](https://github.com/hwalsuklee/awesome-deep-text-detection-recognition); a few links talk about hand writing recognition.

Comment: Thank you Suhas. I will go through these and let you know for any questions.